# How to have a component display different content depending on what link the user clicked on in a separate component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, http-get

I have a component that displays a list of movie genres generated from a Movies API. What I want is that when the user clicks on the specific genre it displays the movies from that specified genre.

My problem is that the only way I can think of doing this is to literally make a different component for each genre, make a different action creator for each genre in my Redux that does a GET request to the API for each genre, and set the Link to that component for the specified genre. That seems really time-consuming and inefficient.

Is there a way I can make the ShowGenres component display different movies depending on what genre the user clicks on in the Genre component or is the solution I thought of the only way?

Here's my Redux:

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from "redux";
import axios from "axios";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

export const displayGenres = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        axios.get("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key=<api-key>&language=en-US").then(response => {
            dispatch({
                type: "DISPLAY_GENRES",
                genres: response.data.genres
            })
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })
    }
}

export const selectedGenre = id => {
    return dispatch => {
        axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=<api-key>&language=en-US&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=1&primary_release_year=2017&with_genres=9648`).then(response => {
            dispatch({
                type:"SELECTED_GENRE",
                select: response.data.results
            })
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })
    }
}

const reducer = (prevState = {}, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case "DISPLAY_GENRES":
            return {
                genres: action.genres
            }
        case "SELECTED_GENRE":
            return {
                select: action.select,
            }
        default:
            return prevState
        }
    }

const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

export default store;
```

Here's my Genres component that displays all the individual Genres for the user to choose:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {displayGenres} from "./redux";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";

class Genres extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.displayGenres();
    }

    render(){

        const mappedGenres = this.props.genres && this.props.genres.map(genre => {
            return (
                    <div className="mappedGenres">
                        <Link to="/showGenres">{genre.name}</Link>
                    </div>    
            )
        })
        return(
            <div>
                <Navbar/>
                <div className="genre">
                    {mappedGenres}
                </div>
            </div>

        )
    }
}

export default connect(state => state, {displayGenres})(Genres);
```

And here's my ShowGenres component where I want to display movies depending on the Genre that the user clicks on in the Genre component:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {selectedGenre} from "./redux";
import {displayGenres} from "./redux";


class ShowGenres extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.selectedGenre(this.mappedId);
    }

    render(){

        const mappedId = this.props.genres && this.props.genres.map(id => {
            return id.id;
        })

        const mappedSelected = this.props.select && this.props.select.map(genre => {
            return (
                <div>
                    <h1>{genre.title}</h1>
                </div>
            )
        })

        return(
            <div>
                {mappedSelected}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default connect(state=> state, {displayGenres, selectedGenre})(ShowGenres);
```

Comment: have a query string in the links and fetch the data for that genre and then the display is basically movies so it will work anyways in the same component as you will pass it movies belonging to the selected genre

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is to have a method that takes input and sets the state with said input. Now where you go with it from here can vary.

You can have the second component nested inside the first, pass the method as a prop, and for each movie, add an on click event listener that fires the method from props, passing the genre of the movie you clicked as a parameter. The method has to be binded to the parent before being passed down to a child

Will write up an example and post shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example. There's a minor bug somewhere, but the general idea is there. I've used it before but it's been almost a year since touching react. Forgive the sloppiness

```js
const AllMovies = {
  Horror : ['Tax Season', 'Family Dinner', 'DMV Trip 3'],
  Comedy : ['Pasion of the Christ', 'The Earth is Flat'],
  Romance : ['Me, Myself and Bacon', 'There\'s Something About Ice Cream']
}

class Movie
  {
    constructor(title, genre)
    {
      this.genre = genre;
      this.title = title;
    }
  }

class ChildContainer extends React.Component
{
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);

  }
  
  GenerateList()
  {
    let output = [];
    for (var genre in AllMovies)
    {
      let movies = AllMovies[genre];
      for (let i = 0; i < movies.length; i++)
      {
        output.push(new Movie(movies[i], genre))
      }
      
    }
    return output.map(movie => {
      return(
        <li onClick={() => this.props.CallParent(movie.genre)}>
          {movie}
       </li>
          )
    })
  }
  
  render()
  {
    return(
      <ul>
        {this.GenerateList()}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}


class ParentContainer extends React.Component
{
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      CurrentValue : []
    }
    
    this.PropMethod = this.PropMethod.bind(this);
  }
  
  PropMethod(newValue)
  {
    console.log('__GENRE__ : ', newValue);
    let genre = AllMovies[newValue]
    this.setState({
      CurrentValue : genre
    })
  }
  
  render() {
    let genres = this.state.CurrentValue.map(val => {
      return(<li>{val}</li>)
    })
    return(
      <section>
        <ul>
          {genres}
        </ul>
        <ChildContainer
          CallParent={this.PropMethod}
          />
      </section>
    )
  }
}



class App extends React.Component 
{
  constructor(props) 
  {
    super(props);
  }
  


  

  
  render() {
    return(
      <section>
        <ParentContainer/>
      </section>
    )
  }
}


React.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**UPDATE**
It should work now :D

There's another way. Remember that all of these components are classes. You can create an instance of both and pass one function to the others props as well. This will allow you to do it without nesting them in eachother.